# Why does it take Noriko so long to get home?

Tags: anime, ftl-drive

In the final episode of *Top o Nerae! Gunbuster*,

> Noriko arrives at Earth to find that it's been ten thousand years since she left, due to the relativistic way FTL travel works in the Gunbuster universe.

Why has it been so long, when the previous trip only took a few years? Did they know it would take so long when they left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most widely accepted explanation is that the time gap has nothing to do with traveling and was instead caused by spending time very close to the event horizon of a massive black hole. Strong gravity fields cause the same relativistic effects as traveling near light speed.

They only got so close to the bomb to make emergency repairs, so it was not planned and they did not know what would happen in advance. Once they got out, they got home quite quickly using the regular Tannhauser jumps.